# import all resources from DigitalOcean with Pulumi

Tags: digital-ocean, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

We use DigitalOcean and have a bunch of resources ( Volumes, DNS, FW, K8s, Droplets and and and ).

Now we want to move to Pulumi to handle all the changes and upcoming new resources in our DigitalOcean Cloud.

What i've searching for is: how can i all resources first import to pulumi without make a import statement for every resource ( this can be a problem because of forgotten and overlooked resources and inconsistency after import )

thx for every idea or solution note

I have searched for globaly import commands but only find commands per resource....

Answer (score 0):

When using `pulumi import` you can specify a file containing multiple resources. E.g. `pulumi import -f <path to json file>`

The format of the file is:

```json
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "docker:index/container:Container",
            "name": "backend-container",
            "id": "1cff08113e52781b1643097c947fa4fe92139a76a020d51c4856bf73207894a2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the [documentation for bulk import](https://www.pulumi.com/learn/importing/bulk-importing/)